# Using both chained done and then for multiple async calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have two methods that have ajax calls inside them, they are named setEmployees and getAllRecordsForEdit. I have a code that should be executed after setEmployees is done; another code that should be executed after both setEmployees and getAllRecordsForEdit are done; and another code that should be executed if getAllRecordsForEdit fails. Now I have this:

```
$.when(setEmployees(selectedEmployeeId), getAllRecordsForEdit(date, selectedEmployeeId))
.done(function (a, b) {
    console.log('setEmployees is done')
    console.log('both are done');
}).fail(function(error) { });
```

So this is called once both are done. In this case setEmployees can be finished before getAllRecordsForEdit, but done will be called once both are finished, so how can I optimize this? Where should I add the code for when one of the methods is done or when the fail for the second is done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$.when(setEmployees(selectedEmployeeId))
        .then(function () {
            //do some stuff after setEmployees
            return getAllRecordsForEdit(date, selectedEmployeeId);
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            //do some stuff after both
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            //handle error
        });
```